# ¿Como consultar el mes actual y los próximos 15 días del siguiente mes MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

hola estoy haciendo un query para consultar el mes en curso pero no entiendo como llamar en la misma query los próximos 15 días del próximo mes, este es el código que tengo actualmente:

```html
SELECT CONCAT(fecha,' - ',dia) AS fecha_concat, 
    horas, 
    personasd, 
    estado
from personas
WHERE
MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

en resumen necesito consultar el mes actual + los 15 días del mes siguiente.

Comment: Podrías complementar con un ejemplo de lo que buscas para que te podamos ayudar?

Comment: Es importante que añadas a tu pregunta la definición de la tabla sobre la que ejecutas la consulta. Como texto, preferiblemente.

Comment: es obvio que la tabla el campo fecha es date, y solo necesito consultar este mes y los próximos 15 días del mes siguiente...

Comment: @fr_oc no, no es obvio, y por eso pedimos que aclares esas cosas. Porque con esa actitud podriamos decirte es obvio que tenes que hacer un between entre el primero del mes y 45 dias despues....

Comment: si fuera varchar se puede ocupar la propiedad month?, tienes la solución en código amigo?

Comment: si fuera varchar que cosa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el DATE_ADD de MySQL para ir agregando dias y meses. 
Hagamos lo siguiente, en vez de ser un mes especifico que sea entre un intervaldo de fechas con el **BETWEEN**, este intervalo sera desde el primer dia del mes en curso

```
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01')
```

Y los 15 dias del mes siguiente

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```

Prueba el siguiente codigo:

```
SELECT CONCAT(fecha,' - ',dia) AS fecha_concat, 
       horas, 
       personasd, 
       estado
from personas
WHERE fecha BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```

> Con el aporte de **gbianchi** quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT CONCAT(fecha,' - ',dia) AS fecha_concat, 
       horas, 
       personasd, 
       estado
from personas
WHERE fecha BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-15'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Comment: te podes ahorra un date_add en el segundo valor si en lugar de usar 01 como dia directamente pones 15 ;)

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por el aporte, edite la respuesta con tu solución. Tienes razón.

Comment: muchas gracias esta solucion andaba buscando, solo le agregue al final: AND YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURDATE()) para el año en curso..

Comment: @fr_oc eso que agregaste no sirve de nada.. esto ya devuelve el año en curso... Ademas, con eso que agregaste, en diciembre-enero la consulta va a dejar de funcionar...

Comment: toda la razon @gbianchi jeje no me había percatado jeje

Answer (score 1):

La solución que planteas podría mostrar el mes actual de otros años que no sean el actual.

Te propongo la solución que te indica @gbianchi:

```
SELECT * FROM fechas
  WHERE fecha BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01')+INTERVAL 45 DAY;
```

Así como el dataset que he utilizado para las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE fechas(
    id_fecha int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fecha date
  );

INSERT INTO fechas (fecha) VALUES 
  ('2018-11-04'),
  ('2019-11-04'),
  ('2019-12-15'),
  ('2019-12-21'),
  ('2019-12-22'),
  ('2019-12-25');
```

Con el que puedes obtener estos resultados:

- Para tu consulta:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM fechas WHERE MONTH(fecha)=MONTH(NOW());
>
> 04/11/2018
> 04/11/2019
> ```

- Para la que te propongo:

> ```
> 04/11/2019
> 15/12/2019
> ```

Comment: Esto no consulta el mes en curso y hasta el 15 del mes siguiente... esto consulta los proximos 45 dias...

Comment: Efectivamente, ya está resuelto... Gracias @gibianchi

Comment: no. sigue estando mal.. now + 45 da mas que el 15 del mes siguiente... Si vamos a chupar una idea de un comentario, mejor hacerlo bien ;)

Comment: Pues sí, y además citándote... :D ya lo tienes